# Async Pipe in Template inside ngFor block triggers http GET calls loop

Tags: angular, typescript, observable, rxjs5

I have the following component Template:

```
<div *ngFor="let ctrl of data; trackBy:ctrl?.Id">
   <div *ngIf="getNext(ctrl.nextDate) | async as next">
        <span>{{next | date: 'dd.MM.yyyy'}}</span>
   </div>
</div>
```

getNext() is a simple method returning an `Observable<Date>`:

```
public getNext(deadline: string): Observable<Date> {
   return this.http.get<Date>(`${this.config.apiEndpoint}/api/meeting?deadline=${deadline}`);
}
```

My goal would be to invoke the method and subscribe to the observable with the async pipe in the template. However when I run the application endless GET and OPTIONS requests are generated.

Also if I place the method call outside the ngFor the same happen. The call would need to be executed inside the ngFor as the parameter is different for each collection item.

Why the method is simply called once and no more calls generated after the subscription?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Calling functions in template is usually not a very good idea as it leads to unpredictable results. This is how you can restructure your code to avoid this:

```
data: any = [....] // some data
data$: Observable[];

ngOnInit() {
    this.data$ = this.data.map(elem => this.getNext(elem));
} 

public getNext(deadline: string): Observable<Date> {
   return this.http.get<Date>(`${this.config.apiEndpoint}/api/meeting?deadline=${deadline}`);
}
```

And in your template:

```
<div *ngFor="let ctrl of data$">
   <div *ngIf="ctrl | async as next">
        <span>{{next | date: 'dd.MM.yyyy'}}</span>
   </div>
</div>
```

Here's a stackblitz I created where you can see how a similar mechanism works: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nyn4qz

Comment: *"Calling functions in template is usually not a very good idea as it leads to unpredictable results. "* - what is an example of an unpredictable result ?

Comment: @Zze an unpredictable result is for example exactly the problem in the question :)

Comment: Lol, exactly :D

Comment: @VictorNoël It's not unpredictable as explained in your answer. It is working exactly as expected, although unfortunate - the cyclic change detection which is causing this issue. Although be it the accepted answer, in this answer there is no explanation of what the actual issue was in the first place.

Comment: @Zze you are right, it is unpredictable in the sense that it never does what a developer who would use a function in a template would expect it to do. Thanks for the vote of confidence anyway!

Comment: This works around a problem avoiding to understand  the cause. "Calling functions from templates isn't a good idea why? What about calling a function to react to click or type events? Is that also a bad idea? Why?

Answer (score 4):

Angular calls `getNext` every event cycle, and each time `getNext` makes new `http` request and returns new `Observable`. You need to cache `Observable` from first function call. I recommend you to create them somewhere in controller, and then pass in template as variables.

Answer (score 3):

Most certainly your problem is related to change detection.

Everytime angular considers there can be changes to what is necessary to draw your template (i.e. anytime there is a browser event except if your component is `OnPush`), it will redraw the component, and thus retrigger the loop and the observable.

In that case you have two choices:

- ensure change detection is not triggered when not needed (for example by making your component follow the `OnPush` `ChangeDetectionStrategy`) but it mostly work only if there is a limited set of `@Input()` that triggers the update of the component.
- do the requests only once in `ngOnInit` or in `ngOnChanges` (in the case `data` is an `@Input()` of your component)  and store the results in an array that you base your template on to do the for loop (I would go this way).