# Cloud function firebase call with angular/ionic cant get result but work with curl

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic-framework, google-cloud-functions

I'm developping a small application for a project for class in which I must fetch some users data from firebase. For that I choosed to use a cloud function to retrieve all users. Here the code of my function.

```
import { Request, Response } from 'express';
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
import * as cors from 'cors';
const corsHandler = cors({origin: true});

admin.initializeApp();

const getAllUsers = (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  corsHandler(req, res, () => {
    const maxResults = 1000; // optional arg.
    const allUsers: any = {'email': [], 'uid': []};
    admin.auth().listUsers(maxResults).then(
      (userRecords: { users: any[]; }) => {
        userRecords.users.forEach(userRecord => {
          // For each user
          allUsers['email'].push(userRecord.email);
          allUsers['uid'].push(userRecord.uid);
        });
        return res.status(200).send(JSON.stringify(allUsers));
      }).catch((error: any) => {
        console.log("Error listing users:", error);
        return res.status(500).send(error);
      });
  })
}

module.exports = {
  api: functions.https.onRequest(getAllUsers),
};
```

The problem is on the angular side, I'm trying to get the result of this function, if I use curl, no problem I get all the informations I need. But when I'm using an angular service, it's stucked in an infinite loop. Here my code :

```
<p> {{ this.authService.getAllUsers() | async }}  </p>
```

In my html file, I just want to print the result and in my service :

```
  import { functions, auth } from 'firebase';

  getAllUsers(): Promise<any> {
    //return this.http.get('https://XXX.cloudfunctions.net/api').toPromise();
    return functions().httpsCallable('getAllUsers')();
  }
```

As you've seen I should get a promise out of these two results so I don't know where the infinite loop may come.
In the console I don't see any error...

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this in your `auth.service.ts` code :

```js
getAllUsers(): Observable<any> {
  return this.http.get('https://XXX.cloudfunctions.net/api');
}
```

in your component ts:

```js
  allUsers$: Observable<any>;

  ...

  ngOnInit() {
    this.allUsers$ = this.authService.getAllUsers();
  }
```

in your component template:

```html
<p> {{ allUsers$ | async }}  </p>
```

`async` pipe will automatically subscribe to `allUsers$` observable, and it will fetch the `HTTP GET` request to your `Cloud function`.

**Important**: never use functions inside your template and especially with `async` pipe.

Due to change detection system, Angular needs to execute function to know if its result has changed.

In case of a function returning an `Observable` with a delay (http request for example), Angular will subscribe to it via `async` pipe, and trigger a new time the change detection when result is coming to redraw the component, which will create a new observable via the function... infinite loop hence.

See for example [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48813002/async-pipe-in-template-inside-ngfor-block-triggers-http-get-calls-loop).

**Improvment suggestion** (not directly linked to issue) :

Also, it should be better to type your response, for example:

```js
getAllUsers(): Observable<ApiResponse> {
  return this.http.get<ApiResponse>('https://XXX.cloudfunctions.net/api');
}
```

Comment: Thanks ! It works ! But why could the fact of not using a variable to store observable could lead to an infinite loop ?

Comment: I've updated my answer to give more details on loop issue.